# Переадресация через проверку сессии

Tags: php

Вот такая у меня проверка сессии

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and    !empty($_SESSION['password']))
        {
        //если    существует логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем, действительны ли они
        $login = $_SESSION['login'];
        $password = $_SESSION['password'];
        $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM    users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'",$db);
        $myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM    users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'",$db);
        $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        if (empty($myrow2['id']))

           {
           //Если не действительны (может мы удалили    этого пользователя из базы за плохое поведение)
            exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен    только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
           }
        }
        else {
        //Проверяем,    зарегистрирован ли вошедший
        exit("Вход на эту    страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!"); }
```

На главной странице я пытаюсь сделать переадресацию с главной страницы на другую страницу, если у пользователя активна сессия.

<? if ($myrow['login'] == $login
                       {
            }
            else
            {
            header('Location: page.php?id/');
            }
?>
 Он у меня не работает. Что не так?

Comment: Если добуквенно, то тут синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($myrow['login'] == $login) { } else { header('Location: page.php?id/'); }
```

Скобку не закрыли.

Comment: naym, спасибо! Случайно удалил, что даже не заметил.